# Spark 1.5.2: Pre vs post sorting of dataframes

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` with columns  `id (long), name(String)` randomly distributed across all the rows of the dataframe. The goal is to split the dataframe for unique value of `id`s and then write out a `sorted` dataframe (wrt `name` field) to disk. There are two ways to do this:

The first approach is to sort the dataframe first:

```scala
//Approach 1: Global sorting (Psuedo code)
val df_sorted = df.sort(col("name"))
val unique_ids = df.distinct().head().getLong(0)
// write out to disk 
for specificID in unique_ids
     df_unique = df.filter(col("id") = specificID))
     // write to disk
     df_unique.write(...)
```

The second approach is to sort the dataframe before writing to disk

```scala
//Approach 2: Local sorting (Psuedo code)
val unique_ids = df.distinct().head().getLong(0)
// write out to disk 
for all specificID in unique_ids
     df_unique = df.filter(col("id") = specificID)).sort(col("name"))
     // write to disk
     df_unique.write(...)
```

Which one is supposed to provide better performance? In approach(1), the entire dataframe can be sorted in `O(NlogN)` time where `N` is the number of rows. In the second approach it can be sorted in `k/N (k/Nlogk/N)` where `k` is the number of unique ids (assuming uniform distribution). More important, it can be sorted locally within a partition.

Comment: I don't get it neither.

Comment: This code isn't Python nor Scala. I'm running blind...

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto is says pseudo-code. But I still don't get what and why the OP is doing.

Comment: @eliasah As far as I understand the idea is to simply get data partitioned by some value and sorted by another. More or less secondary sort.

Answer (score 1):

For starters in the second case data cannot *be sorted locally within a partition*. Since we're working under the assumption that *randomly distributed across all the rows of the dataframe* applying `sort` after the `filter` is a distributed operation and same as in the first case requires a full shuffle. To make it local you would have to `coalesce` to a single partition but this once again a full wide operation.

The second issue is the assumption that the first case is *O(NlogN)*. Even if you assume that Spark sorts in *O(NlogN)* you'll still have *O(KN)* to apply all the filters. In practice Spark sorts using approach similar to bucket sort:

- first it build a `RangePartitioner` over the data
- repartitions data using the partitioner
- sorts locally within each partition

I non-distributed application one could argue this *O(N + K)* on average but it clearly ignores distributed nature of application. Moving data from partition to partition is not the same as moving data in memory and has its own complexity which depends further on the configuration and cluster topology.

Finally `DataFrame` API is declarative. It means that what you write is not necessarily what you get.

Putting all the details aside we can simplify this problem and choose one of two basic strategies

1. Sort (range partition) first

   - range partition data by name
   - for each partition:

     - sort data within partitions by name
     - write data using separate file for each id
   - *(optionally)* - combine partial files for each id
2. Partition by id first

   - (range) partition data by id:
   - for each partition:

     - sort data within partitions by name
     - write data using separate file for each id

As you can see this basically the same algorithm.

Comment: You begin by stating  "data cannot be sorted locally within a partition"; while in (2) i.e. partition first, you say "sort data within partitions by name" ?

Comment: @Neel This was just about your specific approach. When you `df.filter(col("id") = specificID))` rows are scattered all over the cluster.  So subsequent `sort(col("name"))` is not local.

Comment: Correct approach is to either ensure key distribution (partition by id) or values distribution (range partition - sort and then partition internally (write by name).  This means that there is only one global operation.

Comment: In your own code both operations (filter and sort) are global. You could the first partially local by using `df.sort(name).write.partitionBy(id)` but it is not the same as iterative filter.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the correct approach? How would you refactor the pseudo-code in that case? If I write out the local partition to disk, how do I ensure, that for the same id, all the rows have been sorted correctly wrt the name field?

Comment: `df.sort("name").write.partitionBy("id").format(...).save(...)` is the only way that comes to mind which is expressible using `DataFrame` API. It will create a single file per (id, partition) pair though. The second approach is pretty easy with RDD and either one-to-one partitioner or `MultipleTextOutputFormat`.

Comment: but when you are calling `sort("name")`, isn't that distributing all the rows across the cluster?  if you now call `partitionBy("id")`, its going to induce a heck of a shuffle?

Comment: `partitionBy` is a writer method. It doesn't repartition data. It simply splits the output. If it trigger a shuffle it wouldn't be viable solution.

Comment: Ok. You're correct that I will have files generated per `(partition,id)`. Now how do I get a global sorting of the `name` field across all the partitions?

Comment: You already have one. Order of `names` -> order of partitions (which is reflected by file names.

Comment: I am missing it. So, here is a flow: Original DF has rows (100, "z"), (116,"a"), (12, "g"), (150, "e"), (18, "c"), (22,"b"). After df.sort(name), let's say we have partition1: [( (100, "z"), (116,"a")] partition2: [(12, "g"), (150, "e")] partition3:[(18, "c"), (22,"b")]. After sorting (by name) we have,  partition1 =  [(116,"a"), (100, "z")], partition2: [(150, "e"), (12, "g")], partition3 = [(22,"b"),(18, "c")]. Now write.partitionBy(..), will generate 6 files across all the partitions i.e. 116(content:a), 100(content:z), 150(content:e), and so  on.. How are they sorted globally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104811/discussion-between-zero323-and-neel).

Comment: @Neel Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks !